# How Convert to Rx java Observable

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to convert `Void` and `Response` type to `Observable` corresponding. I tried `.just` but `.create` not sure if I can use just or create to do this conversion. Thanks.

```
void getSomeValue(){
    Observable<Response> returnedObservable=getResponse();//How to convert this from Response to Observable<Response>
    Observable<Void> returnedObservable=doSomething();//How to convert this from Void to Observable<Void>
}

Void doSomething(){
   //some code...
   return null;
}

Response getResponse(){
  //some code....
  return someResponse;
}
```

Comment: See `from` section. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small note: RxJava provides several types of observables (see [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-types-of-observables-in-rxjava-6c3a2d0819c8)). For this case, there is no reason for returning an `Observable<Void>`, you can use a `Completable`: in fact, it represents a deferred computation without any value.

You can use the method `fromCallable`: this defers the execution of `getResponse` function until the `Observable` is subscribed. The eager approach consists to use `just`: it evaluates the function immediately in the current thread.

```
Observable<Response> response = Observable.fromCallable(this::getResponse);
Observable<Response> response = Observable.just(getResponse());
```

Same for `Completable`:

```
Completable something = Completable.fromAction(this::doSomething);
```